# Ошибка в файле XML

Tags: php

Имеется некоторый file.xml

В этом файле, имеется узел, например, title, который содержит следующий текст

```
<title>Дом & Печеньки</title>
```

Такой файл отдаст ошибку из за амперсанта (&) в нем. Как в момент открытия исправить нужный узел (title) обернув содержимое узла в CDATA ?
XMLReader и simplexml не открывают файл ввиду ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы именно заменить данные в файлы, надо загрузить его например через `file_get_contents` и потом преобразовать данные

```
$string = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $string);
```

Но в целом, чтобы проблем не возникало, наверное стОит записывать данные как сущности. Т.е. использовать `htmlspecialchars`  перед записью в файл XML

Comment: Заменять & на &amp; нельзя, к сожалению..нужно чисто как есть строку в CDATA обернуть т.к. вместо & может появиться иной символ, который поломает XML. Советуют сделать регуляркой, но я даже не представляю, какая это регулярка должна быть т.к. внутри <title> могут быть еще узлы типа <ru><en> и др